# Zero-or-one-to-one relation and one-to-many relation using annotations in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a migration for a code-first model in which one entity has two relations to another entity. One relation is 1:N and the other is 0:1:

```
public class Checkpoint
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Count")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual Count Count { get; set; }
}

public class Count
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Checkpoint CurrentCheckpoint { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Checkpoint> Checkpoints { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

The idea behind this is that there is one count (the process of counting things, might take some time) which has many checkpoints, and one of those checkpoints is the "most recent" checkpoint which serves as an indicator for doing calculations.

I have tried a myriad of combinations of `Required`, `InverseProperty` and `ForeignKey` but haven't been able to make this work. The closest I've gotten generated column names that won't work for us, and I think wasn't correct anyway, something like this:

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Count", t => t.Count_Id)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Count", t => t.Count_Id1)
.Index(t => t.Count_Id)
.Index(t => t.Count_Id1);
```

Unfortunately these names don't match the class properties and aren't descriptive, so I would need to change them (which is how I got started on this journey). Also I would think it should use `t.Id` in both cases...but maybe not. Is this possible with annotations in EF6?

Comment: Your `Count` entity doesn't have a primary key on it so EF is trying to create one for you. Add a `public long Id` property to `Count` and mark it as the `[Key]`. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Oops, it does, actually. I'll update...

Comment: It isn't marked as `Key` though, it just has an `Id` property.

Comment: Foreign keys can only point to the primary key of another table. If it's not marked as `[Key]` then EF may figure it has to create a primary key for your foreign key to point at. Migrations sometimes has a mind of its own.

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit Foreign Key to Checkpoint? IE add `public long CountId` with the annotation `[ForeignKey("Count")]`

Comment: I wonder if a 1:1 association is appropriate here. What happens to a `Checkpoint` if it's no longer current?